# Problema con código JS en Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código `JS` de una páctica, lo pego a codeen.io y me funciona, pero dentro de mi mac, con visual studio code no me funciona, solo está asimilando las instrucciones dentro del `else` y no las que están dentro del `if`:

```
document.getElementById("boton").onclick=function(){
    if (document.getElementById("girar").style.background == "red"){
        document.getElementById("girar").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
        document.getElementById("girar").style.transition = "all 3s";
        document.getElementById("girar").style.background = "black";
        console.log("Negro");
        } else {
        document.getElementById("girar").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
        document.getElementById("girar").style.transition = "all 3s";
        document.getElementById("girar").style.background = "red";
        console.log("Rojo");
        }
};
```

Y este el código `HTML`:

```
<div id="girar" class="contenedor" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black;"></div>

<div class="cont-btn">
    <button type="reset" id="boton">¡Ponlo a Girar!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba cambiando el comparador del **if**  de esto `==` por esto `===`

Comment: Sigue sin hacer nada. ¿Qué será?

Comment: Probé tu código y funciona , lo que hace es poner a girar el cuadro negro y convertir el color a rojo y viceversa

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que hace, cosa sencilla. Pero lo que no entiendo es porque en este editor no me lo está haciendo.

Comment: Sale algo en la consola de VS code?

Comment: Dentro del IF puse un console.log("negro"), lo mismo dentro del else, console.log("rojo"). Cuando le doy al botón, en la consola aparece rojo solamente, indicándome que solo ha recibido las instrucciones dentro del else. Solo eso.

Comment: Yo entiendo que el visual studio no tiene nada que ver aqui, en todo caso tendrías que ver la consola del navegador a ver que dice.

Comment: si ya has intentado ver que dice la consola? (F12)

Comment: por qué no nos pasas el código que usas en vbc exactamente?

Comment: Ya sé lo pasé. Ver arriba.

Comment: A todos: lo probé, como alguien me aconsejó, en otro navegador y sí me funcionó. En Mozilla Firefox no me funcionó y en otro navegador si. ¿Qué raro, verdad?

Comment: Digo raro, porque siempre he escuchado que Mozilla es el navegador predilecto del desarrollo Web.

Answer (score 1):

bienvenido.
Como ya te pudiste dar cuenta, en algunos navegadores sí te funciona y en otros no, como es el caso de Firefox.

Si haces un `console.log()` de el `document.getElementById("girar").style.background` te darás cuenta que el resultado es: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%

Por ello no ingresa a la condición.
Una posible solución sería en lugar de utilizar el "==" usar "indexOf"

```
document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function() {
    // puede ver acá lo que imprime en el style.background
    console.log(document.getElementById("girar").style.background)

    if (document.getElementById("girar").style.background.indexOf("red")>-1) {
      document.getElementById("girar").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
      document.getElementById("girar").style.transition = "all 3s";
      document.getElementById("girar").style.background = "black";
      console.log("Negro");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("girar").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
      document.getElementById("girar").style.transition = "all 3s";
      document.getElementById("girar").style.background = "red";
      console.log("Rojo");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Tienes razón, me funcionó como dijiste. Mil gracias. Y aclarame una duda, que significa: *red none repeat scroll 0% 0%*

Comment: son las propiedades de background en una linea css, "color, imagen, si se repite, posición y tamaño"